# What function and parameters are available in Pandas in order to open a tab delimited text file?

Tags: python, pandas, python-unicode, csv

I have a text file as follows:

```
   Movie_names Rating
      "A"         10
      "B"         6.5
```

The text file is tab delimited. Some movie titles are enclosed in a double quote. How to read it into a pandas dataframe with the quotes removed from the movie names?

I tried using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("movie.txt")
```

However, it says there is a Unicode decode error. What should be done?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', sep='\t')`

Comment: I get a whole range of errors. It ends with "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte" and it is NOT a file with a csv extension. It has a .txt extension.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ;)

Comment: ok i am deleting the question

Comment: To solve the `UnicodeDecodeError` you need to specify the encoding while loading (see my answer below).

Comment: The encoding error was showing up because the original text file was saved with ANSI encoding. I saved it again with UTF-8 encoding and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can read tab delimited files using either `read_table` or `read_csv`. The former uses tab delimiter by default, for the latter you need to specify it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', sep='\t')
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('yourfile.txt')
```

If you are receiving encoding errors it is because `read_table` doesn't understand the text encoding of the file. You can solve this by specifying the encoding directly, for example for UTF8:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('yourfile.txt', encoding='utf8')
```

If you file is using a [different encoding](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html), you will need to specify that instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to
   import pandas

```
Df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
```

Get rid of double quotes with

```
Df2 = Df['columnwithquotes'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
```

Comment: I get a whole range of errors. It ends with "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte" and it is NOT a file with a csv extension. It has a .txt extension.

Comment: I am using python 3 so that may be reason for the Unicode error. I believe csvreader has ability to read text files and covert to CSV first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read_table` as its `quotechar` parameter is set to `'"'` by default and will so remove the double quotes.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

the_data = """
A   B   C   D
ABC 2016-6-9 0:00   95  "foo foo"
ABC 2016-6-10 0:00  0   "bar bar"
"""
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(the_data))
print(df)

#      A               B   C        D
# 0  ABC   2016-6-9 0:00  95  foo foo
# 1  ABC  2016-6-10 0:00   0  bar bar
```